# Incremental loading Merge or using SSIS

Tags: ssis, merge

I have a scenario. I am implementing Incremental loading using merge statement
on date basis.

But if the data is deleted at source level, we still have the data in the datawarehouse.

How do we handle this kind of scenarios.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Then you reverse your source and reference tables. New/updated data starts in A and looks in B to determine if there is a change. Deleted data, you start with B and look in A for a match. If no match found, delete from B. Whether you stage all the to-be-deleted records to a table and perform a set based delete or use the OLE DB Command within your data flow is a question of volume. If you expect tens, maybe hundreds of deletes, then the performance of the OLE DB Command object will probably be find. If you have millions to delete, you likely will not want to pay the penalty of the row-by-row nature of that component.